# Transform XML inputs (files) to ACCESS outputs (table) using XSL

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I want to transform XML inputs (files) to ACCESS outputs (table) using XSL.
The XML files I have looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_IN>
    <Record>
        <Header>
            <HEAD>HEADOEM</HEAD>
        </Header>
            <ItemMaster>
                <CONO>800</CONO>
                <WHLO>CA</WHLO>
                <STAT>20</STAT>
                <ITNO>PNA</ITNO>
                <SPE3>SPE3 A</SPE3>
                <FRE3>N</FRE3>
                <UNNN>HAZ B</UNNN>
                <HAC1/>
                <HAC2/>
                <ITGR>BAAEAA</ITGR>
                <SPE5/>
                <CSNO>123</CSNO>
                <UNMS>AA</UNMS>
            </ItemMaster>
        <Trailer>
            <TRAIL>TRAILOEM</TRAIL>
        </Trailer>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Header>
            <HEAD>HEADOEM</HEAD>
        </Header>
            <ItemMaster>
                <CONO>800</CONO>
                <WHLO>CB</WHLO>
                <STAT>20</STAT>
                <ITNO>PNB</ITNO>
                <SPE3>SPE3 B</SPE3>
                <FRE3>N</FRE3>
                <UNNN>HAZ A</UNNN>
                <HAC1/>
                <HAC2/>
                <ITGR>BAAEAA</ITGR>
                <SPE5/>
                <CSNO>456</CSNO>
                <UNMS>BB</UNMS>
            </ItemMaster>
        <Trailer>
            <TRAIL>TRAILOEM</TRAIL>
        </Trailer>
    </Record>
</ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_IN>
```

What interested me is getting all the data in the `<ItemMaster>` section.
I don't know how to do this because the "Header" and "Trailer" tags bother me.

That's what I've managed to do so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_IN/Record/Header/HEAD/ItemMaster/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, that doesn't work, I'm really a beginner in XSL, so if you guys could help me, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your XSLT states, that you want to generate XML. Is this correct? Is Access able to read XML?

Comment: Yes, I want to import the data in the XML to a Access Table. But before importing, I want to transform them.

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define template rules for each node to handle them individually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

The rule for the root node needs to output a new root node, because each XML needs a root node.

```
<xsl:template match="/ZBE14_OEMs_ItemUpdate_IN">
  <import>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </import>
</xsl:template>
```

The input `Record` generates an output `row` for the import.

```
<xsl:template match="Record">
  <row>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </row>
</xsl:template>
```

The `ItemMaster` should not be copied.

```
<xsl:template match="ItemMaster">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

`Header` and `Trailer` should be ignored.

```
<xsl:template match="Header|Trailer" />
```

Everything else should be copied.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate the following output:

```
<import>
  <row>
    <CONO>800</CONO>
    <WHLO>CA</WHLO>
    <STAT>20</STAT>
    <ITNO>PNA</ITNO>
    <SPE3>SPE3 A</SPE3>
    <FRE3>N</FRE3>
    <UNNN>HAZ B</UNNN>
    <HAC1/>
    <HAC2/>
    <ITGR>BAAEAA</ITGR>
    <SPE5/>
    <CSNO>123</CSNO>
    <UNMS>AA</UNMS>
  </row>
  <row>
    <CONO>800</CONO>
    <WHLO>CB</WHLO>
    <STAT>20</STAT>
    <ITNO>PNB</ITNO>
    <SPE3>SPE3 B</SPE3>
    <FRE3>N</FRE3>
    <UNNN>HAZ A</UNNN>
    <HAC1/>
    <HAC2/>
    <ITGR>BAAEAA</ITGR>
    <SPE5/>
    <CSNO>456</CSNO>
    <UNMS>BB</UNMS>
  </row>
</import>
```